# last Element in my ul list not being removed from my dynamically generated list

Tags: c#, html, ajax

This is the html code I am using you will see below that the ID I refer to is the SectionList from this ID we populate via ajax post get function below.
the ajax then calls the getsections portions from mvc and then populates it on the front end, it does this on save and delete. The issue here is that I can add new records on the list, I can also delete these records on the list but when it comes to my last record on the list it refuses to update the ul the last record just sticks there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getSections();
});

function getSections() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getSections")',
    type: 'Get',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var total = data.length
      if (total = 0) {
        $("#SectionList ul").html(rows).clear()

      } else {
        var rows = "";
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          rows += '<li id="' + item.SectionID + '" class="col-md-8"><i class="ion-arrow-right-c"></i>' + item.SectionName + '</li>'
          rows += '<li class="col-md-4"><i><button type="submit" id="Remove" value= "' + item.SectionID + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-circle">Remove</button></li>'
          $("#SectionList ul").html(rows);
        });
      }

    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("Error:" + err.responseText);

    }

  });
}

$("#Create").click(function(e) {
  var data = {
    SectionName: $("#SectionName").val()
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Savedata")',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      getSections();
      clear();
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("Error:" + err.responseText);

    }
  });
})

$(document).on("click", "#Remove", function(e) {


  var datas = {
    SectionID: $(this).val()
  }


  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Deletedata")',
    data: datas,
    success: function(datas) {

      getSections();
      clear();
      var elem = document.getElementById("datas");
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
      $(this).parent().remove();

    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("Error:" + err.responseText);

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<section class="checkout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 mr-auto text-left mt40 mb40">
        <div class="section-heading">
          <h5>Assesment Creation - Section </h5>
          <hr class="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label>Section Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" id="SectionName" name="FirstName"><br>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button id="Create" type="submit" value="Creategg" class=" btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-square btn-appear">Add</button>
          <div />
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="SectionList" class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="list-icons">


        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

The below is the Ajax calls that I am using

Comment: your code doesnt execute

Comment: what is "I can delete the the records in the list" mean. How are you deleting the records in the ul?

Comment: The records delete from the database. but on the front end they only get removed up until the 2nd last record, when I click remove on the last record, it removes the record from the database but it doesnt clear out the list

Comment: public ActionResult Deletedata(AssesSection AssesSection)
        {
            
            AssesSection assesSection = db.AssesSections.Find(AssesSection.SectionID);
            db.AssesSections.Remove(assesSection);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(AssesSection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }